# Global .Xsession file

Tags: linux, x11, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to run a Raspberry Pi in kiosk mode. Currently, I have an `.Xsession` file placed in `/home/pi/` that opens the Chromium browser on system boot. Everything seems to work fine for now.

Is it possible to configure the Xsession without placing the `.Xsession` file to pi's home folder? Preferably, I want to have some kind of global settings that would be used for any Linux user.

One reason I need this is that I may need to deploy updates to the Raspberry Pi without being able to interact with the device myself. The updates would just replace existing Xsession configurations etc. with new ones, but I cannot be sure that the default username is pi in the future, i.e., pi might not be the default user anymore or the `/home/pi` folder might not even exist.

Comment: It is not recommended to remove the standard pi user. It may break stuff.

Answer (score 1):

For Debian (and therefore raspbian; & presumably a lot other distros):

- `/etc/X11/Xsession.options`
- or in the directory: `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/*`

Quoting the Debian wiki on [Xsession](https://wiki.debian.org/Xsession):

#### System-wide configuration

> System-wide configuration of the Debian X session consists mainly of options inside the /etc/X11/Xsession.options file, and scripts inside the /etc/X11/Xsession.d directory. These scripts are all dotted in by a single /bin/sh shell, in the order determined by sorting their names. Administrators may edit the scripts, though caution is advised if you are not comfortable with shell programming.